# Cannot combine click tracking and recommendation tracking inside an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, einstein-recommendations

With the help of Eliot Harper and Hans Meijer I started to develop a newsletter that contains salesforce marketing cloud web recommendations. However I don't know how it is possible to create a picture with a href that has tracking functionality inside the newsletter and tracking functionality of the recommendation system.

- The variable @link2 contains the web recommendation url that points to the https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/redirect/...
- The variable @image2 contains the imageurl of the product catalog of salesforce.
- The variable @linkwithhref2 contains the complete href `set @linkwithhref2=Concat('href="',@link2,'"')`

---

I tried these options:

Option 1:

`<a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="%%=v(@link2)=%%" style="text-decoration:none;" title=""><img src="%%=v(@Image2)=%%" style="padding: 0px; height: 250px; width: 250px; border-width: 0px; border-color: transparent; border-style: solid; text-align: center;" width="250"></a>`

Result 1:

- Good: Tracking functionality of the newsletter works (wrapped to https://click. ...)
- Bad: Clicking the image results that the redirect goes to https://click.ourdomain.com/%%=v(@link2)=%%, which is a bad request

---

Option 2:

`<a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="%%=TreatAsContent(@link2)=%%" style="text-decoration:none;" title=""><img src="%%=v(@Image2)=%%" style="padding: 0px; height: 250px; width: 250px; border-width: 0px; border-color: transparent; border-style: solid; text-align: center;" width="250"></a>`

Result 2:

- Good: Tracking functionality of the newsletter works (wrapped to https://click. ...)
- Bad: Clicking the image results that the redirect goes to https://click.ourdomain.com/%%=TreatAsContent(@link2)=%%, which is a bad request

---

Option 3:

`<a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" %%=TreatAsContent(@linkwithhref2)=%% style="text-decoration:none;" title=""><img src="%%=v(@Image2)=%%" style="padding: 0px; height: 250px; width: 250px; border-width: 0px; border-color: transparent; border-style: solid; text-align: center;" width="250"></a>`

- Bad: Tracking functionality of the newsletter does NOT work (no link wrapping to https://click.ourdomain.com ...)
- Good: Clicking the image results that the redirect goes to https://nova.collect.igodigital.com/redirect/..., and then redirects to our website, which is the behaviour we want to achieve.

---

How can i combine both functionalities (click tracking inside the newsletter and click tracking of recommendations). Any comments or hints welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [RedirectTo()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirectto.htm) function.  Something like:

`<a conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="%%=RedirectTo(@link2)=%%" style="text-decoration:none;" title=""><img src="%%=v(@Image2)=%%" style="padding: 0px; height: 250px; width: 250px; border-width: 0px; border-color: transparent; border-style: solid; text-align: center;" width="250"></a>`

This function is designed to handle all AMPscript variables used as links to ensure they are correctly wrapped for tracking.

ALSO, I have run into cases where with WAC turned on, if you do not have an alias, then it will break the link. So try adding in something like:
`<a conversion="false" data-linkto="https://" href="%%=RedirectTo(@link2)=%%" style="text-decoration:none;" title="" alias="Image2"><img src="%%=v(@Image2)=%%" style="padding: 0px; height: 250px; width: 250px; border-width: 0px; border-color: transparent; border-style: solid; text-align: center;" width="250"></a>`

Comment: Great answer. I should have also known that but sometimes you just forget some functions :D Can you tell me what WAC means? Its no typical abbreviation I know, googling it gives me answers that do not fit, one of these: https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/WAC ? I believe its "works as coded" but i am unsure. One stuff you could change: correct the code in your answer that it doesnt contain two aliases

Comment: Web Analytics Collector for SFMC

Comment: Is there a best practice what you should insert in the alias? Is it a productname like "2345" or a region like "link3". Where does this pop up and does title will be shown when you insert a text?

Comment: Aliases have to be static text, not variables.  They show as aliases for links in tracking in Email Studio, in the _Click data view and in the Click tracking extracts.